# Align table cells to the left

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML table, 100% width, with 4 columns ...

When the table is very large and the data in the columns is small I get a large space between columns ...

Would be possible to make all the columns next to each other and leave that white space only on the last column?

Comment: example code please!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but you could give the first three columns a width (if you know what width you want) and leave the fourth unspecified. The fourth column will then auto-adjust to take up the 'slack'.